# Is there a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> True or false: there  exists   a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the open interval $(0, 1)$.

I think this  is  false, because  $R^2 - \{0\}$  is connected but $(0,1) = R$ as  $R-\{0\}$  is  not connected, as the continuous  image of a connected set is connected.

Comment: You only insist that there be a bijection : you do not insist that it is continuous. Connectedness arguments apply if the latter was true.

Comment: There are two results that you should be aware of.  1) For $A$ an infinite set, one has $|A|=|A\times A|$.  2) $|\Bbb R| = |(0,1)|$.  Next, you should remember how bijections are used in the definition of equality of cardinalities.

Comment: thanks@астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг,,,

Comment: thanks @JMoravitz,,,

Comment: @stupid You are welcome. A related fact to this problem, but much harder, is the "invariance of domain" property of $\mathbb R^n$, which you may read up.

Comment: True (and interesting) is what you proved: there is no **continuous** bijection between $\mathbb R^2$ and $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is True.

At this time I cannot provide the explicit bijection BUT the idea is this:

> Schroder–Bernstein Theorem:
>
> Assume there exists a $1–1$ function $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and another $1–1$ function $g : Y \rightarrow X$. Then there exists a $1–1$, onto function $h : X \rightarrow Y$ and hence $X ∼ Y$ .

Define $f:(0,1) \rightarrow (0,1)\times (0,1)$ by $$f(x)=(x,1/3)$$
Then $f$ is injective.

Define $g:(0,1)\times (0,1) \rightarrow (0,1)$ by $$g(x,y)=0.x_1y_1x_2y_2....$$
where $x=0.x_1x_2x_3....$ and $y=0.y_1y_2y_3....$ and where we make the convention that we always use the terminating form over the repeating $9's$ form when the situation arises.

Then $g$ is injective. (Prove this!)

Hence $$(0,1) \sim (0,1) \times (0,1)$$

We know $(0,1)$ and $\Bbb{R}$ are equivalent,via $$x \mapsto \tan \pi (2x-1)/2 $$

So, next map $\Bbb{R}^2$ bijectively onto the open unit square $(0, 1)\times (0,1)$ by mapping each $\Bbb{R}$ bijectively onto the open interval $(0, 1)$

Hence $$ (0, 1)\times (0,1) \sim \Bbb{R}^2 $$

> Summary:
>
> $$(0,1) \sim (0,1) \times (0,1) \sim \Bbb{R}^2$$

In addition, if your function is continuous, then this is not true!

Comment: You described $f$ and $g$ as 1-1, i.e. bijective. This is wrong, $f$ and $g$ should be both $\textit{injective}$.

Comment: @teddy38 although it is traditionally worded with injectivity, the version worded with surjectivity instead is true too.